# Selenium StaleElementReferenceException when accessing table data on a website

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm working on a Python program to scrape data from the following website using Selenium and BeautifulSoup: https://www.argentina.gob.ar/desarrollosocial/registrocuidadores

I have managed to navigate through the steps to access the first table I need using the code. However, after that, the WebDriver closes itself and I encounter the following error in the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/martin/Desktop/Scrap/scrapy1-3.py", line 33, in 
    select2.select_by_visible_text(option2.text)
  ...
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

I am using the Chrome browser with version 109.0.5414.87.

Could you please provide any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue with the StaleElementReferenceException? Thank you.

This is my code right now:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    '/Users/martin/Downloads/chromedriver_mac64/chromedriver')

# Abrir el sitio web
driver.get("https://registroncd.senaf.gob.ar/ListadoCuidadores.aspx")

# Esperar a que la página cargue antes de hacer scraping
time.sleep(3)

boton1 = driver.find_element(
    By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_DropDownListProv']")
select1 = Select(boton1)
options1 = select1.options

for option1 in options1:
    select1.select_by_visible_text(option1.text)
    time.sleep(3)  # wait for the page to load
    boton2 = driver.find_element(
        By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_DropDownListLoc']")
    select2 = Select(boton2)
    options2 = select2.options

    for i in range(1, len(options2)):
        option2 = options2[i]
        select2.select_by_visible_text(option2.text)
        time.sleep(3)  # wait for the page to load
        boton3 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_ButtonBuscar")
        boton3.click()
        time.sleep(3)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1")))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
        table = soup.find("table", class_="gridview")
        if table:
            rows = table.find_all("tr")
            for row in rows:
                cells = row.find_all("td")
                for cell in cells:
                    print(cell.text)
        else:
            print("La tabla no ha sido encontrada")
```

Comment: At which step are you stuck exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use only `bs4` without `selenium` you can try:

```py
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# first page:

url = 'https://registroncd.senaf.gob.ar/ListadoCuidadores.aspx'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

data = {}
for inp in soup.select('input[value]'):
    data[inp['name']] = inp['value']

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(url, data=data).content, 'html.parser')

df = pd.read_html(str(soup))[0]
print(df[:-1])

# for additional pages:

for page in range(2, 4):
    data = {}
    for inp in soup.select('input[value]'):
        data[inp['name']] = inp['value']

    del data['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ButtonBuscar']
    data['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1'
    data['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = f"Page${page}"

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(url, data=data).content, 'html.parser')

    df = pd.read_html(str(soup))[0]
    print(df[:-1])
```

Prints:

```
                Nombre   Apellido         Provincia     Localidad       Telefono                          Email Capacitaciones
0       BLANCA BEATRIZ    AGUILAR      Buenos Aires    25 de Mayo  0234515532692  lucianamaraportilla@gmail.com            Ver
1        RUBEN OSVALDO  CABALLERO      Buenos Aires    25 de Mayo  0234515400320  lucianamaraportilla@gmail.com            Ver
2      DAVID ALEJANDRO     GIGLIO      Buenos Aires    25 de Mayo  0234515517152  lucianamaraportilla@gmail.com            Ver
3       LILIANA RAQUEL  MACHAROLI      Buenos Aires    25 de Mayo  0234515438703  lucianamaraportilla@gmail.com            Ver
4   PATRICIA ELIZABETH     MATTIA      Buenos Aires    25 de Mayo  0234515433654  lucianamaraportilla@gmail.com            Ver
5       ANDREA SILVINA      PEREZ      Buenos Aires    25 de Mayo  0234515513612  lucianamaraportilla@gmail.com            Ver
6      NATALIA CLARISA      LOPEZ      Buenos Aires    25 de Mayo  0234515400562  lucianamaraportilla@gmail.com            Ver
7       LUCIANA KARINA       MARA      Buenos Aires    25 de Mayo  0234515668788  lucianamaraportilla@gmail.com            Ver


...and so on.
```

Comment: That's works great. Thanks. But how I change the range to extract all the information?

Comment: @Martin Increase the `range(2, 4)` to get the number of pages you want.

Comment: Andrej, thanks for your help. I'm looking a way to know the exact number of total pages in the site. I've tried using request or a while loop but I can't get to resolve it. Can you help me in this last thing? I've also found the way to extract all the information to a .cvs file so everything is looking fine besides that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `WebDriverWait`

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_ButtonBuscar"))).click()
```

**import**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```